# I want to display items in list according to Categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't display products according to their Categories

Althought when i run the app all products are displayed and the category (either Men or Women) is written under every product but when i try choosing products from (Men Category) it displays EMPTY LIST

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 3;
    public ProductController(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }
    public ViewResult List(string category, int Page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel 
        { 
         Products= repository.Products
                     .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                     .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                     .Skip((Page - 1) * PageSize)
                     .Take(PageSize),


         pagingInfo = new PagingInfo
         {
             CurrentPage = Page,
             ItemPerPage = PageSize,
             TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
         },
         CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(model);

    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:model-view-controller] tag is for the pattern, for the implementation your referring to use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag.

Comment: If you want to display products for a particular category, why do you have a `.Where(p => category == null ...` which would also include products with no category. The code you have shown will return results assuming there are products with categories that match the `category` parameter

Comment: I'd double check your `category` parameter to make sure it really exists in your database. Also, you'll want to set your `TotalItems` based on your query result and not the total count of products in your database. I would expect that to match my category filter.

Comment: Are you sure your `category` parameter isn't an empty string instead of `null`?

Comment: the proplem is when there is only 1 product of the category (Men) 
it works
but when there's more than 1 product with the same category it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
p.Category.Equals(category, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

instead of

```
p.Category.equal == category
```

Comment: the proplem is when there is only 1 product of the category (Men) it works but when there's more than 1 product with the same category it doesn't work